# When is $f\ne 0$ in the interior of $\text{supp}\ f$?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

**Question:** Is $f\ne 0$ in the interior of $\text{supp}\ f$? $\color{blue}{\text{(Resolved).}}$

---

**Question 2 (more interesting):** If we can find a counterexample, then exactly what property characterizes those functions $f$ such that $f\ne 0$ in the interior of $\text{supp}\ f$? This would most likely also depend on $X$, i.e. it is locally compact and Hausdorff or not, etc. In my opinion, this is a very deep question, and my gut says that we should be able to find some interesting results which help us understand the behavior of functions from their support sets. $\color{red}{\textbf{(Unresolved).}}$

---

$\text{supp}\ f$ is the support of $f:X\to \Bbb C \text{ or }\Bbb R$, a real/complex valued function on a topological space $X$.
$$\text{supp}\ f = \overline{\{x: f(x)\ne 0 \}}$$
It is clearly possible that $z\in \text{supp}\ f$, but $f(z) = 0$ still. For example, let $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ given by
$$f(x) = \begin{cases} x & 0\le x < \frac{1}{2} \\ 1 - x & \frac{1}{2} \le x \le 1 \\ 0 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$$
Here, $\text{supp}\ f = [0,1]$, but $f(0) = 0$ and $f(1) = 0$. However, what struck me was that $(0,1)$ is the interior of $[0,1]$, the support of $f$. So is it always the case that we take a point in the interior of the support of a real/complex-valued function $f$ on a topological space, $f$ is non-zero at that point?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I doubt if there is any useful sufficient condition for this.

Comment: Wasn't there a bounty on this, still active?

Answer (score 5):

The support of $f(x)=|x|$ is the whole real line . $0$ is an interior point and $f(0)=0$.

Comment: Also works with $f(x) = x$.  Any function with an isolated zero.  Any function zero on a nowhere dense closed set (like the Cantor set).